# for loop trouble, running only throug the first instance of the list

Tags: python

My code is web scraping some data to obtain stock fundamental info such as Price to Book etc.

I'm trying to run a for loop in order to remove additional HTML code as some data points are colored on the website.

When I try to run the for loop to strip the data from additional HTML code, code for color in this case, it only runs through once for the first point in the list of colors (HTML codes)

My output looks like this:

```
3.49
0.77
4.88
<span style="color:#aa0000;">15.71</span>
<span style="color:#aa0000;">8.07</span>
2.72
None
None
<span style="color:#aa0000;">10.19</span>
None
<span style="color:#aa0000;">7.21</span>
4.34
1.54
<span style="color:#aa0000;">10.75</span>
```

code:

```
import time
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import pandas as pd

sp500short = ['a', 'aa', 'aapl', 'abbv', 'abc', 'abt', 'ace', 'aci', 'acn', 'act', 'adbe', 'adi', 'adm', 'adp']
#stock = 'a'

data = []

color_1 = '<span style="color:#008800;">'
color_2 = '<span style="color:#aa0000;">'
color_list = [color_1, color_2]
color_close = '</span>'


def finvizPBStats(stock):

    pbr = 0

    try:

        sourceCode = urllib.request.urlopen('http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t='+stock).read()
        sourceCodeString = sourceCode.decode()
        pbr = sourceCodeString.split('P/B</td><td width="8%" class="snapshot-td2" align="left"><b>')[1].split('</b></td>')[0]

        for color in color_list:
            if color not in pbr:
                return pbr
            elif color in pbr:
                pbr = pbr.split(color)[1].split(color_close)[0]
                pbr = float(pbr)
                return pbr


    except Exception as e:
        if Exception:
            pass 

for stock in sp500short:
    print(finvizPBStats(stock))
```

Comment: You `return` inside the `for` loop. it will break the `for` loop and go out of the function. If you just want to `continue` to the next option in the `for` - use `continue` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you need the first `if` condition in the loop.

```
   for color in color_list:
        if color not in pbr:  # No need to have an if
            return pbr
        elif color in pbr:
            pbr = pbr.split(color)[1].split(color_close)[0]
            pbr = float(pbr)
            return pbr
```

If the color is not in the list, go on to the next one. If that is not in the list, then return `pbr`

```
   for color in color_list:
        if color in pbr:
            pbr = pbr.split(color)[1].split(color_close)[0]
            pbr = float(pbr)
            break  # exit the loop
    return pbr
```